# Программная смена табов в андроид приложении

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, android-tablayout

Здравствуйте. Есть TabLayout. А в нем три таба. По нажатию на элемент в 3 табе (фрагмент) нужно переключиться на 1 таб(другой фрагмент) с передачей параметров и обновлением данных во фрагменте
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно реализовать?
Cитуация такова, что у меня есть фрагмент(хост), в котором содержится ViewPager и TabLayout.
А контент табов (их 3) это есть фрагменты.
И вот при определенной ситуации нужно переключиться из одного фрагмента в другой
Как мне из дочернего фрагмента достучаться до ViewPager, который содержит эти фрагменты?

Вот класс фрагмента хоста:

https://github.com/Denchabaev/SchoolDiary/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/dchabaev/schooldiary/fragments/SchoolJournalFragment.java

А фрагменты, которые являются табами лежат в пакете fragments/tabs.

Cуть вопроса заключается в том, что я не знаю, как из фрагмента достучаться до viewholder, который содержится во фрагменте-хосте. Заранее спасибо за ответы)

Answer (score 1):

Должно по идее сработать

```
getParentFragment().mViewPager.selectPage(1);
```

Только `mViewPager` должен быть публичным.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Так  не получилось, но я сделал так в методе onCreateView фрагмента, с которого нужно переключиться. Не знаю правильно \то с точки зрения ООП, но работает:// нам нужно достучаться до viewPager,
                // для этого ищем активити -> фрагмент-хост -> viewPager
                MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) getParentFragment().getActivity();
                // устанавливаем первую вкладку по клику
                mainActivity.getSchoolJournalFragment().getViewPager().setCurrentItem(0);

Answer (score 0):

Можно из 3-го таба кидать интент и ловить его в хосте ресивером, а там получать номер фрагмента на который нужно переключиться и указывать пейджеру какой сделать активным. А вот по передаче параметров тут можно интент перенаправить в целевой фрагмент также через broadcast.